# When I try to make an object transparent, the object is not evenly selected. Why?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

[image]I want to make an object(looks like thin rectangular sheet) transparent from top to bottom.For that I made a transparent material and tried to apply the material to the object by selecting the top and bottom sides. Since the object is having see thorough holes in it(from top to bottom), I can't apply the transparent material to the sides.That is, I cant select the object's face evenly. As a result unwanted lines that connect the holes and the boundary are appearing and the transparent operation is not able to be performed. Kindly help me make my object transparent. Thank you very much for your time and support.

Comment: I am not sure what you want exactly. Can you share some more screens about what it does now and what cca you want? You want sides to be solid but top and bottom transparent (you mean those holes are transparent or what?! I am really confused

Comment: Just select the entire object, use the Principled BSDF shader with the Transmission set to 1 and Roughness to a low value like 0.1.  That gives a look like perspex which I assume is what you want?